# how do I programmatically change icon of a Windows executable and Mac application?

Tags: windows, macos, icons, node-webkit, electron

When distributing standalone applications built on [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) or [Atom Shell](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell), we are really just distributing the framework binary but with our application content in a subdirectory.

We can of course rename the executables to our Application's name, but can we also change the icon (preferably from the command line for automating a release workflow)?

Answer (score 4):

There are solutions for doing this from the command line in both Mac and Windows.

### Mac

```
defaults write /full/path/to/Info.plist CFBundleIconFile 'app/img/my-icon.icns'
```

### Windows

Requires [winresourcer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/winresourcer)

```
  winresourcer --operation=Update \
           --exeFile=path/to/my-exe.exe \
           --resourceType=Icongroup \
           --resourceName:1 \
           --resourceFile:path/to/my-icon.ico
```

To find the `resourceName`, use [Anolis Resourcer](http://www.anol.is/resourcer/) to open the exe.  The name is found on the sidebar as the child element of `Icon Directory`.  In my case, it was simply called `1`.